# Using 3D Raster Domain to get polygon of raster - but stripping Z and M values

Tags: arcpy, 3d

I'm trying to convert a number of large, floating point rasters into polygons so I can view overlaps etc. I've been using 3D Raster Domain sucessfully to do this. The only problem is that the polygons that are created are very large as a Polygon ZM is created, and I really only need a polygon. Any ideas how to do this? I've tried adding this to my script to disable Z and M values:

```
#disable M and Z values in output
arcpy.env.outputZflag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.outputMflag = "Disabled"
```

... but it didn't reduce the size. I don't want to convert them to integer rasters (the original rasters are too numerous and large in size).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the polygons are created as such large sizes, not because they are gaining the additional Z and M flags, but because they have millions of vertices! (Maybe some exaggeration there but.. perhaps you take my meaning.)

My recommendation would be to [try downsampling the raster](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=resample_%28data_management%29) before you vectorize it. (*By the way, never perform destructive edits on your original data!! Make a copy first!!*)

Downsampling means if your raster grid corresponds to---for example---6 inches, you would translate it a larger cell-size, perhaps 1 sq. meter. Or maybe 1 acre. etc. etc. Fewer cells will mean fewer vertices, which will result in leaner polygon geometries. Just realize downsampling is costing you resolution. So you should be mindful to downsample into a reasonable resolution for whatever you're researching. If you're examining elk habitat, you don't need data in sq. inches. :) ...but if you're creating a cost-surface for pedestrian spaces, sq. feet or sq. yards might be reasonable.

If you're not interested in downsampling the raster first, you could always do the vectorization, then followup with [a Simplify operation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=simplify_polygon_%28data_management%29) on your big polygons. This will take the polygons produced from the raster and reduce their densities, in effect accomplishing something similar---though I promise you the mapped areas will be different. The vectors from the downsampled raster will retain a "blocky" edge, while simplified polygons will probably look "jagged".

If I were you, I would downsample first, as I believe this would not only make the best use of your processor time, but also give you more desirable outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made a typo, you aren't actually disabling the [M and Z values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000007000000). ESRI's use of capitalization is very frustrating as syntax errors aren't always returned (it isn't in this case) which makes debugging a pain.

A few weeks back I was working on this exact problem: creating an index shapefile of all the rasters in my directory. My shapefile was reduced from hundreds of megabytes to less than 5MB.

You code should be thus:

```python
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"
```